# How can I use my stored procedure in Entity Framework 4?

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4, entity

I have this stored procedure for login

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_Login

    (
    @username varchar(50),
    @password varchar(50)
    )   
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @loginflag VARCHAR(1)   
IF EXISTS (SELECT dbo.tbl_Login.Id FROM dbo.tbl_Login WHERE (dbo.tbl_Login.LoginId = @username))
    BEGIN
IF ((SELECT COUNT(dbo.tbl_Login.Id) FROM dbo.tbl_Login WHERE (dbo.tbl_Login.LoginId = @username) AND (dbo.tbl_Login.Loginpassword= @password))> 0)
        BEGIN
        WITH LoggedInUser AS 
        (
SELECT  L.LoginId,L.LoginRole,L.LoginPassword,L.UserId,S.FatherName,S.Name,S.RollNo,S.Marks,S.Dob,                    S.Address,S.PhoneNumber,S.CityId,S.EmailAddress,S.Gender,S.Password,             S.SiteUrl,S.StuAvtar,S.StuCv FROM dbo.tbl_Login AS L INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_Student AS S ON L.UserId = S.Id  
                       WHERE L.LoginPassword=@password AND L.LoginId=@username
        )
        SELECT *FROM LoggedInUser

        END
        ELSE        
            SELECT -98 AS Error --User Password Wrong   
    END 
    ELSE 
        SELECT -99  AS Error --USER NOT EXISTS
END
```

and I would like to use it with Entity Framework with return result. How can I do it? please help me...

Answer (score 0):

**There is no direct mapping support** for **stored procedures** when using Code First

You can simply call your procedure **instead of Add method** by using **db.Database.SqlCommand method.**

Try this (**This is a sample**):

**News class:**

```
public class News
{
   public int NewsId { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string Body { get; set; }
   public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

**Connection String**

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add
      name="MyDatabaseContext"
      connectionString="Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**DbContext**

```
public class MyDatabaseContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<News> Newses { get; set; }
}
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[News_Insert]
(
   @Title VARCHAR(100),
   @Body VARCHAR(MAX),
   @NewsStatusId INT
)

AS

BEGIN

   INSERT INTO
      News
      (
         Title,
         Body,
         NewsStatusId
      )
      VALUES
      (
         @Title,
         @Body,
         @NewsStatusId
      );

  SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();

END
```

**How to use SP with above model (code first)**

```
db.Database.SqlCommand("dbo.News_Insert @Title, @Body, @NewsStatusId",
  new SqlParameter("Title", news.Title),
  new SqlParameter("Body", news.Body),
  new SqlParameter("NewsStatusId", news.NewStatus.Id));
```

**Here are some useful links for more details**

[**Nikolaos Blog Post**](http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2011/03/01/using-stored-procedures-with-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-application.aspx)

[**Beyondrelational Blog Post**](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/64/posts/11620/entity-framework-40-bind-stored-procedure-with-result-entity-class.aspx)

Comment: this is wrong entity framework use store procedure with add function functionality that is in built in that when u do click in on model browser u will option

Comment: @KumarAryan you can use above instead of Add method.

Comment: 'There is no direct mapping support for stored procedures' this is simply not true. You cannot map stored procedures when using code first but you can when using Database First. Updated the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

here's a link on how to use the stored procedure by Entity Framework [Stored Procedures in the Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can write stored procedures in sql and your entity update and then conversion it to function and use it such as function in your program,db-click on the Entity Model and in open page(EntityModel) then i right side page db-click on folder that called StoredproceduresEntity and open then right click on the a StoredProcedures and select option AddFunction... then select type of output go to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx

Comment: i want to do login not crud operation :)